# Receive all messages from SAV back office to my mailbox directly prestashop 1.7.8.8

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have one problem in prestashop 1.7.8.8,

I want to receive all messages from SAV back office to my mailbox directly prestashop 1.7.8.8

So when i have one message from contact page or from order message customer, i want to receive one copy of message in my mailbox

How can i do this ? (see picture represent)

Thanks.

I want to receive all messages from SAV back office to my mailbox directly prestashop 1.7.8.8